# MySql Count by Month to show months with no data

Tags: mysql, join

I have been trying to fix my query for days now. It is supposed to group by month and return 0 if record is not found. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
school_id,
IF(school="Utah Valley University","Schoo1",
IF(school="Weber State University","School2", school)) school,  
online,
pif_price,
COUNT(pif_price),
pif_price,
payment_plans.id AS Payment,
COUNT(IFNULL(x1.Month,0))

FROM users

INNER JOIN students 
    ON users.id = students.user_id
INNER JOIN students_terms
    ON students.id = students_terms.student_id  
INNER JOIN terms
    ON students_terms.term_id = terms.id
INNER JOIN courses      
    ON terms.course_id = courses.id 
INNER JOIN schools      
    ON courses.school_id = schools.id
INNER JOIN payment_plans
    ON students_terms.payment_plan_id = payment_plans.id    
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
            DISTINCT MONTH(enroll_date) AS Month,
            enroll_date
            FROM students_terms
            GROUP BY Month ASC) AS x1
    ON students_terms.enroll_date = x1.enroll_date
WHERE
NOT pif_price = 229
AND NOT pif_price = 429
AND NOT pif_price = 1199        
AND students_terms.enroll_date >="2017-01-01"
AND students_terms.enroll_date < CURDATE()

GROUP BY
month
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the numbers 1-12 from a nested table.

Even then, the query runs, but does not bring any data.

I was able to get data again by taking the nested table out, like in the following:

```
SELECT 
school_id,
IF(school="Utah Valley University","School1",
IF(school="Weber State University","School2", school)) school,  
online,
pif_price,
COUNT(pif_price),
payment_plans.id AS Payment,
CONCAT(MONTH(students_terms.enroll_date), "/",     YEAR(students_terms.enroll_date)) AS Enroll_Date

FROM users

INNER JOIN students 
    ON users.id = students.user_id
INNER JOIN students_terms
    ON students.id = students_terms.student_id  
INNER JOIN terms
    ON students_terms.term_id = terms.id
INNER JOIN courses      
    ON terms.course_id = courses.id 
INNER JOIN schools      
    ON courses.school_id = schools.id
INNER JOIN payment_plans
    ON students_terms.payment_plan_id = payment_plans.id    

WHERE
NOT pif_price = 229
AND NOT pif_price = 429
AND NOT pif_price = 1199        
AND enroll_date >="2017-01-01"
AND enroll_date < CURDATE()

GROUP BY 
YEAR(enroll_date),
MONTH(enroll_date),
pif_price
```

Researching here I was able to find that if make a "month table" and join on it, that would solve my problem. The issue is, I do not have permissions to add a table to the DB. And that is why I am trying to get this to work with a nested "month table."

Is there a way to make this code work without having to add the "month table?"

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Before writing an answer which goes in the wrong direction: 1) What data type are `pif_price` and `enroll_date` exactly (to find out, issue `SHOW FIELDS FROM table;` from within MySQL client)? 2) In your first query, you are grouping by `month`, but I can't see this being defined (aliased) anywhere. Where does it come from?